# Python - How to sort a list of alpha and numeric values?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Is there a fast way to sort this list :

```
list = ['J', 'E', 3, 7, 0]
```

in order to get this one (numeric first, and then alpha) in python? :

```
list = [0, 3, 7, 'E', 'J']
```

Comment: Have you tried using the sort function? list.sort() should do what you want.

Comment: Side note, never shadow built-ins, e.g. use `L` or `list_` as variable names.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question because my list is a list of tuples so I'm a bit confused with it...

Comment: Can you update the question with the expected output for the list of tuples example?

Comment: @Raquel Guimarães Yes, sorry. Done :)

Comment: @Feign' For the example, the `.sort()` method should solve your problem. Perhaps you need a more complex scenario.

Comment: I reversed the edit on your question, because if that was your data, you should've said so from the start. Your edit gleefully invalidates every answer here, and that just isn't done, because it isn't fair to the people who've invested time into solving your problem. Now, because of how you framed your question initially, your problem hasn't been solved and our time here has been spent in vain. Please keep this in mind. I recommend opening a new question referencing this one.

Comment: Yes, @Raquel Guimarães. I need to sort a list of tuples (see my edited answer).

Comment: @coldspeed Ok, sorry. I'll accept jpp's solution because it solved this question and ask the part you removed in another post.

Comment: Great, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort with a (Boolean, value) tuple:

```
L = ['J', 'E', 3, 7, 0]

res = sorted(L, key=lambda x: (isinstance(x, str), x))

# [0, 3, 7, 'E', 'J']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with numbers (that, in this case, are <10) and strings, you can simplify your key and remove the `lambda`:

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=str)
[0, 3, 7, 'E', 'J']
```

Or, even better, use `list.sort` for an in-place sorting.

```
>>> lst.sort(key=str)
>>> lst
[0, 3, 7, 'E', 'J']
```

Each item will be sorted based on the ASCII value of the `str`-ified value.

Note that, if you're dealing with numbers >=10 (highly likely), then this solution will end up sorting the numbers lexicographically. To get around that, you will end up needing the lambda.

```
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x: (isinstance(x, str), x)))
```

Which is @jpp's solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use `list.sort()` on you list, you will get

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

You have to convert all items in list into string type.

```
[str(i) for i in list]
```